# How to scrape Google map popular time part

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, request

I want to scrape by selenium or bs4 popular time part of google map is there any way please help me out[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4g07.jpg)

div[role="img"][class^="dpoVld"]

Day name ke liye div[aria-label^="Popular"][role=region] div[role="img"]

Comment: inside each column div u have an aria-label with the percent

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.